# add second database connection

Tags: codeigniter

I try to add a second database connection in my CI Application. The first is initialized by:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

How can I access now a second database connection in my model? I tried this:

```
class Configurator_model extends CI_Model{

private $db2 = null;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db2 = $this->load->database('configurator', TRUE);
}

public function all(){
    $query = $this->db2->get('projects');
    var_dump($query);
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}

}
```

but there are no results. Var_dump returns:

> object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#22 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(47) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(48) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL }

The database is configured like this in the config:

```
...
$db['configurator']['hostname'] ...
...
```

Comment: Maybe related to this blog post? http://koorb.wordpress.com/2007/11/16/codeigniter-connect-to-multiple-databases/

Comment: Your code is fine. Are you sure that you are having the correct values of the 'configurator' connection group?

Comment: Hi, I use the configuration data for a connection right out of Webstorm and it works. What about $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session'); Can this be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I see this on [CodeIgniter Userguide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) Hope this help.

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$this->load->model('Model_name', '', $config);
```

You can save the database in an element of the `$cconfig` variable like `$config['second_db'] and load this config in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

Check out COnnecting to Multiple Databases: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: Be sure, I checked this, but I cannot see an error in my code. It's done like in the manual!

Comment: Try changing:    
$db2 = $this->load->database('configurator', TRUE);

and 

$query = $db2->get('projects');

Comment: The result is the same if I use a local variable.